# SQL, trying to compare 2 int and getting error "Cant compare char and int"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jtable

I'm getting this error:

> "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: No están soportadas las
>   comparaciones entre 'INTEGER' y 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)'. Los tipos deben
>   ser comparables. Además, los tipos de cadena también deben tener una
>   intercalación coincidente. Si la intercalación no coincide, una
>   posible solución es convertir los operandos para forzarlos a la
>   intercalación por defecto (por ejemplo: SELECT tablename FROM
>   sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')"

My database table has 11 positions, everything is a varchar but the first one, thats a int.

And iI' getting data from the `jtable`, everything but the col 0, wich is a int, rest is strings.

And here is my code:

```
int colActual = jTableNombre.getSelectedRow();

private void jButtonGuardarNombreActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     

    String nombre = (String) jTableNombre.getModel().getValueAt(colActual,1);
    String director=(String) jTableNombre.getModel().getValueAt(colActual,2);
    String año = (String) jTableNombre.getModel().getValueAt(colActual,3);
    String generos = (String) jTableNombre.getModel().getValueAt(colActual,4);
    String actores = (String) jTableNombre.getModel().getValueAt(colActual,5);
    String pais = (String) jTableNombre.getModel().getValueAt(colActual,6);
    String idioma = (String) jTableNombre.getModel().getValueAt(colActual,7);
    String doblaje = (String) jTableNombre.getModel().getValueAt(colActual,8);
    String subtitulos = (String) jTableNombre.getModel().getValueAt(colActual,9);
    String ubicacion = (String) jTableNombre.getModel().getValueAt(colActual,10);
    try {   
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql= "UPDATE MOVIES " + 
            "SET NOMBRE = '"+nombre+"', "+
            "DIRECTOR = '"+director+"', "+
            "AÑO = '"+año+"', "+
            "GENEROS = '"+generos+"', "+
            "ACTORES = '"+actores+"', "+
            "PAIS = '"+pais+"', "+
            "IDIOMA = '"+idioma+"', "+
            "DOBLAJE = '"+doblaje+"', "+
            "SUBTITULOS = '"+subtitulos+"', "+
            "UBICACION = '"+ubicacion+"' "+
            "WHERE ID = '"+id+"'";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);                           
        int i= stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.print(i);
        if (i>0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Movie Updated");  
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Movie dindt update");
        }

    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: you are trying to set id which should be an int as a char, as the error message tells you

Comment: Obligatory [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) link...

Comment: Thank you for answering @Theyna can u explain a little further? im new to java/jdbc and im learning by myself. Thanks.

Comment: have a good think about your WHERE ID clause... id shouldn't be 'id'

Comment: @theyna Thank you!! silly me, dindt realize i had '' around it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `id` in this snippet of code:

```
    "WHERE ID = '"+id+"'";
```

Try to add it.

Comment: Thanks! i dindt realize i was setting id as a char, silly mistake... Still very gratefull for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line of code:

```
        "WHERE ID = '"+id+"'";
```

To:

```
        "WHERE ID = "+id;
```

Should work.

Welcome to Java, also I suggest u taking a look on the jdbc docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/ and also as a suggestion I have to u is, if u are getting and SQLXXX Error, always go on debug, print your SQL command and try execute it on any SQL client, could be helpful to find syntax bugs.

C ya.